# Netcat reverse shell

Tags: linux, shell, networking, ubuntu, netcat

I am trying to create a reverse shell for two computers on my network, I used netcat a few years ago, I remember I did something like to listen for incoming connections:

```
netcat -v -l -p <PORT>
```

But now when I try that it doesn't work, I just get the netcat usage:

```
$ netcat -v -l -p 12345
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
      [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
```

Did something changed in the latest netcat releases?

I am using ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Use `ssh` instead. And, http://superuser.com.

Comment: I prefer netcat because it's easy for me to make it work from linux to windows, and sorry I didn't know superuser

Comment: Could someone with proper permissions delete the question? I solved it reading the manual :P

Comment: [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) is much more full-featured than netcat.  Also, you should be able to delete your own question.

Comment: ephemient: I see the "edit" link, but no "delete", could you guide me?

Comment: @Meredith why not post back an answer explaining *how* you solved it, to help the next person seeing this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a bajillion different `netcat` variants out there.  (Okay, not really; maybe half a dozen major ones.)  Each has different features.

In Ubuntu, you can install `netcat-openbsd`, `netcat-traditional`, `netcat6`.  `netcat` is simply a symlink managed by `update-alternatives [--display/--set] nc`.

`netcat-openbsd` is most likely to be installed and set as default by Ubuntu 10.04 (and is directly depended upon by `libvirt-bin`), but your option set only works on the other implementations.  You can use `nc.traditional` or `nc6` (after installing the proper packages, of course), or use `update-alternatives` to set them as the default `netcat`.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the -p you should be listening on port <PORT>.

```
nc -vl <PORT>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 -p source_port
         Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege
         restrictions and availability.  It is an error to use this option
         in conjunction with the -l option.
```

nc -v -l 12345